# How should i convert my AppTheme style to Material component

Tags: androidx, material-components-android, app-themes

//This is my current AppTheme of my application. How should I migrate my AppTheme to Material Components?. I have Migrated my code to AndroidX.

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarSize">@dimen/actionbar_height</item>
        <item name="actionBarSize">@dimen/actionbar_height</item>
    </style>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppThemeMenu" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
```

Answer (score 0):

in order to use the material components, start by implementing the material library in your gradel files:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

Then, got to the style.xml and change the parent to one of the following material parents:

```
Theme.MaterialComponents
Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar
Theme.MaterialComponents.Light
Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar
Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar
Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight
Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar
Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar
```

For more information you can check [this page](https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/) .

For example:

```
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: That didn't work. The app crashes at   activity.getActionBar().show()   with nullPointerException. The context is of Activity and not AppCompatActivity.

Comment: If you're using Material components, you cant's use AppCompat context. The answer I gave you is the answer for your question, so please approve it. If you're still facing problems I suggest you try googling it or asking a new question on StackOverflow. Cheers! :)

Comment: @UnBanned you didn't answer the question. They posted that they were using AppCompat and want to know how to convert. You didn't address how to migrate away from AppCompat.